# Introductory lab on linux with svn

Tags: linux, svn

https://piazza-resources.s3.amazonaws.com/j6zdjr2o14g248/j7hl17d3fku6te/lab1.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIEDNRLJ4AZKBW6HA&Expires=1505775332&Signature=0n1JbqGf5F%2BRtA%2FFmqEgQcdi6iQ%3D

I don't know how to "4. Commit this new file to your repository" (step 3 part 4)

Below is everything I did up to step 3 part 4

```
>>> cd /cmshome/myutorid/cscb07f17_space


>>> mkdir ./lab1


>>> cd lab1


>>> mkdir ./.myrepo


>>> svnadmin create ./.myrepo


>>> pwd


/cmshome/myutorid/cscb07f17_space/lab1


>>> mkdir ./myCode1


>>> svn co file:///cmshome/myutorid/cscb07f17_space/lab1/.myrepo myCode1


Checked out revision 0.


>>> cd myCode1


>>> ls -al


total 0


drwx------ 1 myutorid cmsusers  76 Sep 18 16:01 .
drwx------ 1 myutorid cmsusers 104 Sep 18 16:00 ..
drwx------ 1 myutorid cmsusers 204 Sep 18 16:01 .svn


>>> ls -a


.  ..  .svn


>>> touch A.txt


>>> pico A.txt


Use "fg" to return to nano.

[1]+  Stopped                 pico A.txt
```

Could someone tell me how to commit A.txt into the repository? Does it matter what directory im stationed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to place the file under revision control, for example:

```
svn add A.txt
```

Then you commit changes to the repository using *commit*, for example:

```
svn commit A.txt
```

The examples above are executed in the same directory as the file, but `svn` will deduce the location of the repository as long as commands are executed within the *working copy* (anywhere within `myCode1`).

The *commit* command requires an editor to be configured, alternatively you will need to use the `-m` option to provide a commit message.

By the way, `[1]+ Stopped pico A.txt` means `pico` is *still running* and the file has not necessarily been saved and closed. Is that what you intended?

See the [online version of the manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) for more.